# Wireshark: Wireless controls are not supported in this version of Wireshark

Tags: wireshark, packet

I am running MacOSX 10.10.5, and am attempting to sniff packets on my own network.

I am using Wireshark version 2.0.2(Most current as of post)

How do I access the Wireless Controls?

Image:

[image: Wireshark Error]

Comment: Something somewhere has been mis-configured. Go through these steps to see if that fixes anything: https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding code to caputils/ws80211_utils.c in the Wireshark source to, on OS X, use [the CoreWLAN framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Networking/Reference/CoreWLANFrameworkRef/index.html) to control Wi-Fi adapter channels etc., and then modifying the Wireshark GUI code so that it doesn't check for `#if defined(HAVE_LIBNL) && defined(HAVE_NL80211)` to determine whether the 802.11 utilities in question are present.

Currently, the wireless controls are only available 1) on Linux and 2) on Windows with the AirPcap adapters.  The changes in question would be needed to support them on OS X (and similar changes, as appropriate for the OS in question, for other OSes, if possible).